# Getting started with toolchain: how do I ensure my toolchain is used?

Tags: bazel

I'm getting started with adding a `toolchain` to our build system. Here's the current setup:

```
File structure:

/toolchains/mongo_toolchain.BUILD
/WORKSPACE.bazel
/src/mongo/db/commands/BUILD.bazel
```

The content looks like this:

```
# WORKSPACE.bazel

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name="mongo_toolchain",
    urls=[
        # v4 toolchain for ubuntu/arm64
        "<redacted>"
    ],
    # For some reason the tarball has this prefix which we do not need:
    strip_prefix="<redacted>",
    sha256="<redacted>",
    # Use a local BUILD file from this repository to describe the toolchain:
    build_file="@//toolchains:mongo_toolchain.BUILD",
)

register_toolchains("@mongo_toolchain//:mongo_toolchain")
```

```
# mongo_toolchain.BUILD

load("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")

cc_toolchain_config(
    name = "cc_gcc_toolchain_config",
    cpu = "arm64",
    compiler = "gcc",
    toolchain_identifier = "mongo_v4_gcc",
    host_system_name = "local",
    target_system_name = "local",
    target_libc = "unknown",
    abi_version = "unknown",
    abi_libc_version = "unknown",
    tool_paths = {
        "gcc": "/bin/false", # "v4/bin/g++",
        "cpp": "/bin/false", # "v4/bin/cpp",
        "ar": "v4/bin/ar",
        "nm": "v4/bin/nm",
        "ld": "v4/bin/ld",
        "as": "v4/bin/as",
        "objcopy": "v4/bin/objcopy",
        "objdump": "v4/bin/objdump",
        "gcov": "v4/bin/gcov",
        "strip": "v4/bin/strip",
        "llvm-cov": "/bin/false",
    },
)

filegroup(
    name = "all",
    srcs = glob(["**/*"]),
)

cc_toolchain(
    name = "cc_mongo_toolchain",
    all_files = ":all",
    compiler_files = ":all",
    dwp_files = ":all",
    linker_files = ":all",
    objcopy_files = ":all",
    strip_files = ":all",
    toolchain_config = ":cc_gcc_toolchain_config",
)

toolchain(
    name="mongo_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with=[
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64",
    ],
    target_compatible_with=[
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64",
    ],
    toolchain_type="@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
    toolchain=":cc_mongo_toolchain",
)
```

```
# /src/mongo/db/commands/BUILD.bazel

cc_library(
    name = "fsync_locked",
    srcs = ["fsync_locked.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["fsync_locked.h"],
    # Since Mongo's c++ files' #include directives are `src`-relative, we need to include `src` in the include path.
    copts = ["-Isrc"],
    deps = []
)
```

Note that the `cc_gcc_toolchain_config` uses `/bin/false` for both g++ and cpp. This is deliberate; I want to make the compile *fail* (to prove that Bazel is indeed using my changes).

I ran `bazel build src/mongo/db/commands:fsync_locked` and it *succeeds*:

```
Target //src/mongo/db/commands:fsync_locked up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/src/mongo/db/commands/libfsync_locked.a
  bazel-bin/src/mongo/db/commands/libfsync_locked.so
```

I suppose I'm probably missing something. I see other posts (e.g.: [Proper use of toolchain_type in Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379536/proper-use-of-toolchain-type-in-bazel/76385713#76385713)) in which people are establishing a `provider`. I had hoped that I could set it up so Bazel's built-in `cc_library` would "just work" with the toolchain I've set up. Any guidance?

Comment: Are you running the build on `arm64` as your `exec_compatible_with` implies? Can you use `--toolchain_resolution_debug` and add the output to the question?

Do you need the bazel auto-configured C++ toolchains? If not please set `BAZEL_DO_NOT_DETECT_CPP_TOOLCHAIN=1` in your shell to prohibit that and  surface the error better.